# Is there a way to configure jenkins to stop building further, if some of the tests fail during a run

Tags: jenkins

I have configured jenkins to build a job periodically. (every 1 hour)

I would like to know if there is a way to configure jenkins, so that, when some of tests fail, the jenkins job stops building after that.

Please help! Thank you!.

Comment: More info needed. You build after tests? Do you want your tests to stop testinh once some do fail? Multiple steps with status evaluation you can do with a wrapper job that executes child jobs)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable jobs using the [REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) (http post to `<jobUrl>/disable`). You can also do that from within a running build.

So, at the end of you job, at a step that -- in case of failure -- will disable the job itself (the build will continue running to the end, but there will not be any further builds).

Comment: can you please detail me on how can i add a step? do you mean "Add build step"? or "Add Post build action"?. I don't see any option in there to disable the job on test failures.

Comment: That's implementation dependent; if you use an `Execute shell` build step for executing your tests, then you could extend that to disable the job in case of a failure. Or -- as you suggest -- you might add a conditional post-build task that only runs upon failure, and which will disable the job then.

Comment: Just realized that your question is a duplicate -- the original questions has a nice solution using the groovy-post-build plugin.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That should work.